# Исключить запись стандартных namespace при записи XML

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При записи объекта в xml получаю следующее(см. скрин). Как сделать так чтобы запись, которая следует после тега report и до тега eeprom не было. И как еще добавить в начало файла следующее

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("","");
s.Serialize(xmlWriter, objectToSerialize, ns);
```

[enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/935749/1985167)

Answer (score 1):

Для задания настроек сериализации используется класс [XmlWriterSetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx), который имеет параметры

- **OmitXmlDeclaration** - возвращает или задает значение, определяющее, следует ли опустить XML-объявление.
- **Encoding** - Возвращает или задает тип используемой кодировки текста.

Тогда ваш код будет иметь следующий вид

```
XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));

// объект, который сериализуем
Report obj = new Report();
// опускаем все определения пространств имен
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("","");
//получаем поток, куда будем записывать сериализованный объект 
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathXmlFileWrite, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
   XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = false, Indent = true, Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")  });
   formatter.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
}
```

В настройках сериализации мы явно указали не удалять [XmlDeclaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256048(v=vs.110).aspx) и установили кодировку Latin1(ISO8859-1) через свойство Encoding.

Comment: Все равно то что находится после report(красным цветом) записывается в xml

Comment: @SVD102, все что пишется после report должно удалиться, используя ответ выше. Мой ответ это ответ на вопрос, как задать кодировку в xml определении. Я не стал дублировать ответ выше. Вы пробовали свой код с объединением этих ответов?

Comment: @SVD102, отредактировал ответ. Добавил опускание всех пространств имен при сериализации объекта.

Comment: Не могу понять как объединить ваш код и который выше.

Comment: @SVD102, я уже объединил его, попробуйте

Comment: Cпасибо, работает

Comment: @ Alexcei Shmakov http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498526/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E-xml-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B2-pathxmlfilewrite-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4

Comment: @ Alexcei Shmakov Так, вот в чем проблема. При считывании я сохраняю в строку кодировку, но когда записываю она не много изменяется почему то. До считывания "ISO8859-1" и после записи "iso-8859-1"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36406/discussion-between-svd102-and-alexcei-shmakov).

Comment: Как ее заменить?