# Сохраняю xml по указанному пути и имени, которые считал в pathXmlFileWrite, вроде записывает файл с тем же именем, но отображает не как xml файл

Tags: c#, xml

Сохраняю xml по указанному пути и имени, которые считал в pathXmlFileWrite, перезаписывает файл с тем же именем, но отображает не как xml файл.

```
XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
//получаем поток, куда будем записывать сериализованный объект
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathXmlFileWrite, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    formatter.Serialize(fs, report);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По коду вроде все правильно, единственное что вы стрим не закрыли, но сомневаюсь что дело в этом

Comment: Пожалуйста, перестаньте в заголовок пихать весь вопрос. Заголовок должен быть короткий, а текст вопроса должен раскрывать всю суть. А не дублировать текст вопроса в заголовке.

Comment: @SVD102 так XML вроде корректен, может дело в IE?

Comment: @Prvz  В чем, что такое IE?

Comment: @SVD102 Internet Explorer, которым вы открываете свой XML, и в котором он отображается некорректно.

Comment: @Prvz Вот что заметил, выложу скриншоты.

Comment: Два документа на последнем скриншоте отличаются только форматированием XML.

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь открыть XML-файл в браузере. Поскольку по структуре XML и HTML довольно-таки близки, то браузер пытается отрендерить ваш XML как если бы это был HTML-документ.

Поэтому все теги XML распознаются как невалидные теги HTML и благополучно вырезаются вместе со всеми своими атрибутами. Остаётся только содержимое тегов `<tagname> value </tagname>`. Это числа, вы их видите на странице IE.

Не открывайте XML в браузере. И вообще ничего кроме веб-страниц в нём не открывайте. Для просмотра кода и данных в различных форматах удобно использовать инструменты, специально заточенные под разработку. На Windows это, например, notepad++, sublime text, любая интегрированная среда разработки (Visual Studio)

Comment: ♦ Как это исправить?

Comment: Документ который справа, его уже я не могу открыть моей программой.

Comment: ♦ Нашел вроде ошибку. Не верно сохраняет кодировку при считывании, и далее она используется при записи. Заглавные буквы переходят почему-то в обычные и удаляется тире.До считывания <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1" ?> и после записи <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer (IE) можно использовать для просмотра XML, он использует для этого родной парсер от Microsoft и строит полное дерево XML с возможностью разворачивать и сворачивать узлы, что довольно удобно, когда надо быстро посмотреть результат без редактирования. Других браузеров это не касается, хотя возможно кто-то из них такое тоже умеет. Chome - не умеет точно.

При этом **IE довольно капризно относится к кодировкам и валидности разметки**. Например "голый", но валидный XML без заголовка с указанием версии и кодировки IE показать может, но только при условии что файл будет в UTF8, заголовок с этой кодировкой IE добавит сам. С другой кодировкой и без заголовка или просто невалидный XML, IE не покажет, точнее покажет пустую страницу.

В вашем случае в заголовке не указана кодировка и очень похоже, что IE просто не распознает или распознает неправильно отдельные символы, используя кодировку по-умолчанию, в отсутствие прямых указаний и поэтому показывает как умеет, отбросив все непонятное. Кроме этого, крайне важно чтобы кодировка, указанная в заголовке, и реальная кодировка файла совпадали.

Стоит обратить внимание, **XML может содержать ссылки на XSLT**, которую автоматически подтянет и применит парсер, а следовательно, IE покажет преобразованный документ. Это, пожалуй, единственное, для чего IE стоит использовать применительно к XML, хотя и для этого есть специальные средства, но удобных и бесплатных я пока не видел

Еще один вариант - **XML с указанием чем именно его открывать**, например документы MS Office сохраненные как XML. Это хоть и экзотика, но лучше быть готовым к таким сюрпризам.

Ну и пожалуй не стоит использовать IE для просмотра **больших XML**, т.к. это будет очень медленно и печально, и пожрет много оперативной памяти.